# How to make a Linear Layout scrollable when orientation is changed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-orientation

Im Designing a Tile like structure for an App Main menu. for this ive used some Linear Layouts with weight so that the Tiles(ImageButtons) will arrange properly. but when i change the orientation of the phone to Landscape the width of the ImageButtons changes (the whole layout), to avoid that im using the following code

```
   @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            findViewById(R.id.activity_MainMenu).setPadding(400,0,400,-250);
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            findViewById(R.id.activity_MainMenu).setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);
        }
    }
```

Now the tiles arranges properly since im giving 400 padding from right and left and -250 padding from the bottom. but only half of the buttons are being displayed. to avoid this i've added a scrollview but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<ScrollView
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/activity_MainMenu"
         android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
         android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
         android:paddingLeft="16dp"
         android:paddingRight="16dp"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/LL1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_weight="1">

             <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/LL11"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:orientation="vertical">

                 <ImageButton
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="0dp"
                     android:layout_weight="1.5"
                     android:id="@+id/button_fitness"
                     android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                     />

                 <ImageButton
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="0dp"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                      />

                 <ImageButton
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="0dp"
                     android:layout_weight="1"/>

             </LinearLayout>


         </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/LL2"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_weight="1">


             <ImageButton
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="0dp"
                 android:layout_weight="1"/>

             <ImageButton
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="0dp"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>


         </LinearLayout>


     </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove android:orientation="horizontal" from the ScrollView.

Also, Why do you have 2 LinearLayout with height = match_parent inside 1 LinearLayout?

Using android:layout_weight="1", the height should be 0,

```
<LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/activity_MainMenu"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/LL1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="0"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_weight="1">
       </LinearLayout>
       <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/LL2"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="0"
             android:orientation="horizontal"
             android:layout_weight="1">
       </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i've added the whole components(ImageButtons) to single Linear Layout since a scrollview can only have one components inside it to scroll.
By adding android:layout_weight="1" and android:layout_height="0"
will not give the desired output.